# Retrieving error info from a string

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have a string with this example error

`File "/home/mdk/Documents/PyPad/src/New289429.py", line 1
    print("SDADADFDSFDSDSFS)
                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Now this is the code that gives me that string:

```
    def execute(self, command):
    """Executes a system command."""

    out, err = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    self.output = out
    self.error = err
    return self.error
```

I need to strip out everything out of that string except for the SyntaxError part and the text after it. Like this: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest way to do that is to grab last line from `stderr`:

`self.errow = err.split(os.linesep)[-2]`

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve that part of the string

```
self.error = self.error.split(os.linesep)[-2]
```